# Save data for tableview coredata in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data, multidimensional-array

I have passed two parameters from another tableview in order to save my notes "my Text" in different array. I just want to save myText for different row for the tableview but now i can just save and see the common myText.

```
var allnote = [NSManagedObject]()

var csname:Int = 1

var cspath:Int = 1

func saveNote(myText:String){

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Logitem", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

let notes = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

notes.setValue(myText, forKey: "itemText")

allnote.append(notes)

var error: NSError?

if managedObjectContext.save(&error) {
println("Couldn't save\(error?.userInfo)")
}

fetchnote()

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You have already two request to close this question for lack of clarity. Please rephrase your question so other people can understand it. What exactly is your problem? What is not working? What do you expect and what is the (undesired) outcome?

Comment: I have a tableview with a following detail view. In the detail view I have to save and edit data. Now no matter what detail view I am in, I am still working on the same data. I just want to save and edit data separate for different detail view. That's why I create two parameters for this aims.

Comment: Your code contains a lot of errors. You should not deal with Core Data at your stage of programming proficiency. Please do a couple of simpler projects first, follow a few tutorials, and then revisit this issue.